# android studio - Gradle DSL method not found: 'compile()' Error:(36,0)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Hi people i have the following error on the title im so done of searching for a solution and still got nothing :'( this is a project for my company and it is 1 month of work please help me I really need my project back .

This is my build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter() // or mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha3'
    }
}
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "nunoalmeida.atphc"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }

    buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter() // or mavenCentral()
        }
        dependencies {
            compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
            compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
            compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.+'

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this , it worked for me
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0'

Comment: it says that can´t find 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0' do I need to download something ?

Comment: No it  should reflect automatically

Answer (score 0):

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter() // or mavenCentral()
    }
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.0-alpha3'
    }
}
```

cut this code from your module level build.gradle file and paste it to your project level build.gradle file.

it worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Download the Gradle distribution and read the "User Guide" PDF from top to bottom and save yourself the time that you'll spend asking questions.

If you do that, you'll find that buildscript dependencies are set with "classpath", not "compile".